# Is having two scanf or getchar() inside and outside a loop necessary?

Tags: c, scanf, string-length, getchar

I saw this little program that calculates the characters length in my practice book, and I am a bit confused. Why is there two `getchar()`, one outside of and one inside the loop?

I removed the `getchar()` outside of the loop and don't see any difference. Is there any consequence if I delete it?

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char ch;
int len;

printf("Enter your message:");
ch = getchar();

while(ch != '\n') {
    len++;
    ch = getchar();
}

printf("Your message is %d characters long", len);
return 0;
```

And here is my modified version, I have no idea if there's any drastic consequence since the output is the same:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char ch;
int len;

printf("Enter your message:");

while(ch != '\n') {
    ch = getchar();
    len++;
}

printf("Your message is %d characters long", len);
return 0;
```

Comment: `while(ch != '\n')` The first time that runs in your version,  `ch` is not initialised and using it results in undefined behaviour (assuming all your code is actually inside a function).

Comment: `int ch; .... while ((ch = getchr()) != '\n' && ch != EOF)` is more common.

Comment: "program that calculates the characters length in my practice book" and `char ch;` instead of `int ch;` implies OP needs a better book.

Comment: @anastaciu - it's *global* it's initialized zero by default (now why it is global is another question) -- it doesn't make much sense as written.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, that must be it, since no functions are presented, one can assume that.

Comment: You can also ponder using a `for` loop, e.g. `int len = 0; for (int c = getchar(); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getchar(), len++) {}`

Answer (score 2):

Both code snippets may invoke [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) because `len` may not be initialized (unless it's a global variable, in which case it'll be initialized to `0`, though there is no good reason for that).

Your replacement code has 2 flaws, removing the outer `getchar()` makes the program evaluate `ch` before it's initialized, invoking again undefined behaviour, and it counts one more character than the actual length of the `char array`.

There are several ways to fix this, one of them could be to change the `while` to a `do-while` loop, and initilaize `len` to `-1`:

[**Running sample**](https://onlinegdb.com/H175KZhII)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int ch, len = -1;

    printf("Enter your message:");

    do {        
        ch = getchar();
        len++;
    } while (ch != '\n' && ch != EOF); //allways a good practice to check for EOF

    printf("Your message is %d characters long", len);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without a `getchar` on the outside, the value of `ch` isn't initialized, which means there's a chance that it could be `\n` to start with and the loop never runs. Also, with your loop, the reported length is one more than the actual length (`a\n` shows as a length of 2 when it should be a length of 1).

Comment: Oh thanks! I didn't notice that the result of my modified version is one more than the original, and if I may, could you tell me why the original is correct and my version is wrong in output?

Comment: The original checks the character before incrementing the length, yours increments the length before checking the character.